# How can I associate different fields in the Device feature class of a domain network

Tags: arcgis-pro, utility-network

The Device feature class in a domain network of UN is common for transformers and switches. But they should be particular fields for transformer like Power Kva and particular fields for switch like normal position (open/closed). these fields will be in the same Device Feature class ? Or I have to create separate Feature Class in the Utility Network for each one for each one ?